# How can I connect to a db4free.net database with PHP?

Tags: php, database

I made a db on db4free.net, and I want to connect to it with php:

```
$username = myusername; 
$password = mypw; 
$host = "db4free.net:3306"; 
$dbname = mydbname; 

$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'); 

try 
{ 
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options); 
} 
catch(PDOException $ex) 
{ 
    die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
}
```

And I get this error message: Failed to connect to the database: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host

So I was thinking , that the hostname is wrong, so i tried to varie it a bit (adding /dbname or /username or removing the port, ect.). I've tried all the combinations, but none of them worked. The login data are checked multiple times. What could be the problem?

Comment: Try connecting to `85.10.205.173` - looks like the DNS resolution doesn't always work.

Comment: Read the documentation of db4free or contact their support...?!

Comment: I would be the happiest if I could talk to the support, but my english is really bad, I wouldn't be able to communicate with them. (And no supp in my country...). Documentation? Where?

Comment: sounds like they are out of order in many aspects, their web page do not load aslo.  Change to other provider searching "free online mysql"

Comment: Ok then, thank you. This is gonna be the 5th move today.

Comment: Well, you get what you pay for, ey?

Comment: @deceze Exactly xD I would need it for testing before actually paying for one.

Comment: @AndréDaniel I tried 85.10.205.173, and now it saies: Can't connect to MySQL server on '85.10.205.173' (4) . Not my day...

Comment: how can I do it with .net

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me...

```
$host = "db4free.net";
```

Comment: yeah, me too, successfull on python too

Comment: i am not able to connect with this also. I am getting an error  : Unable to connect: Access denied for user 'root'@'129.41.86.1' (using
        password: YES)

Answer (score 9):

I tried using this code and it worked for me

```
$host = "85.10.205.173:3306";
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be too late to post an answer to this question.

But I hope this would help anyone who comes searching a solution for a  connection failure or access denial just as me.

db4free.net while having database listening on the port 3306, they provide mysql servers on some other ports as well. When creating your account make sure to keep in mind the server you selected.

As in my case, my account was created on their newly set up [mysql 8 server and it runs on the port 3307](https://www.mpopp.net/category/db4free/)

Answer (score -1):

Don't set the port at the end of the hostname. 3306 is indeed the default port for mysql connection anyway.

Answer (score -1):

If your MySQL is version `8.0.16` you can use this to connect.

```
$host = 'db4free.net:3306'; 
$dbuser = {your-dbuser};
$dbpassword = {your-dbpassword};
$dbname = {your-dbname};

$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$dbuser,$dbpassword,$dbname);
if($conn){
    mysqli_query($conn,'SET NAMES uff8');
    echo "Connection - successful </br>";
}
else {
    echo "Connection - failed </br>" . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

Comment: So how do we connect? You're just declaring a bunch of variables.

Comment: In this answer you can change to your data. If `3306` is invalid you can change the port to `3307`, or see [db4free blog](https://www.mpopp.net/category/db4free/).