# How do I login in to phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin

**Hello Folks..**

*I recently installed 'phpMyAdmin' (with 'Xampp'), but I don't know how it works and I find no solution to my problem on the internet and also not on this forum..*

**First of all my problem:**
I don't know what I have to type in as login information [right here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BCX8.png)...! I can get into phpMyAdmin with '/localhost/phpMyAdmin/' but I can't log in on for example phpMyAdmin demo page or 'db4free.net'. I looked up the whole internet sitting here for three hours and I don't know what to do..

**What I can do:**
[I can get right here...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQMAw.png) I tried changing passwords in FAQ of xampp in the setting of phpMyAdmin and the config. I tried to go to '/localhost/xampp/' but all I get right there is this:

"Index of /xampp

[ICO]   Name    Last modified   Size    Description
[PARENTDIR] Parent Directory        -
Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.6 Server at localhost Port 80"

***I would appreciate your help. Thanks! :)***

Comment: I don't understand why you're mentioning db4free.net or the phpMyAdmin demo page.

Comment: Because I don't know I have to type in there at the phpMyAdmin login page. I can log in locally.. It is set to just log in without having this login page too.(locally), but I want to login on those pages.

Comment: You need to have access to their database in order to be able to use their phpMyAdmin, i.e., you need a valid username and password which they will provide.

Comment: If you want to log in an external database you have to change the host in the config.php.

Comment: Well how do I get it? I didn't find any information and also I tried changing the cookie auth or how it's called to use the login page locally and it didn't work? So I had the same problem. @apokryfos thanks

Comment: @KIMB-technologies can you give me a detailed explanation on how to do it? Would be super cool! :)

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722064/connect-to-external-server-by-using-phpmyadmin and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723625/how-can-i-connect-to-a-db4free-net-database-with-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is not really related to phpMyAdmin. I did just not get how the interface of *db4free.net* works.

Answer (score 0):

try using username as `root` and use password as blank or use the password  that you set

Comment: I tried all combinations with root and tried setting different password but it always gave back "#1045 - Access denied for user 'develop'@'localhost' (using password: YES)". Then I tried changing the using password but it was on true already. So yes..

Comment: It has to be `root@localhost (using password: NO)` to work, so please have a look at your  [PHPMyAdmin config.php](https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/config.inc.php) and uncomment all passwords and usernames.

Comment: $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';   What do I have to change there @KIMB-technologies ?

Comment: No it looks good, because you wrote `'develop'@'localhost'` I thought of an error there.